# How to populate values in associative array javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, associative-array

sorry for my bad english

i am working in javascript and i have build an array i want to enter values in this array.

```
var attribute_sets = [];
$('.attribute_set :selected').each(function(i, selected){
    attribute_sets[i]['id'] = $(selected).val(); // getting id 
    attribute_sets[i]['name'] = $(selected).text(); // getting name
});
```

Its giving me error

> TypeError: attribute_sets[i] is undefined

also tried this one

```
attribute_sets[i]['id'].push($wk_jq(selected).val());
```

still getting same error

can any one please guide me how can i insert values in this JS array.
i want output like this

```
array
    [0]
      'id':'1',
      'name':'abc'
    [1]
      'id':'2',
      'name':'xyz'
```

Comment: What type of elements are you trying to get?

Comment: i am trying to id and name from multi select and i am sending this array to php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try

```
$('.attribute_set :selected').each(function(i, selected){
  attribute_sets.push({
   id: $(selected).val(), // getting id 
   name: $(selected).text() // getting name
});
```

Comment: Thank you so much works like a charm... :) Thanks alot

Answer (score 2):

Use [**`map()`**](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.map/) function.

```
attribute_sets = $('.attribute_set :selected').map(function(i, selected){
    return {
       'id' : $(this).val(),
       'name' : $(this).text(),
    }
}).get();
```

Comment: Thank you so much works like a charm... :) Thanks alot